# MVVM WPF смена DataTemplate если список пуст

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

есть `ListBox`

```
<ListBox x:Name="autoList" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Auto}"  
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuto}">
```

в нем из базы загружаются автомобили.
как сделать чтобы если база пуста(удалены все элементы или еще не заполнялась) `ListBox` заменялся на это

```
<TextBlock Text="Список пуст. Введите данные" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью DataTrigger без дополнительных свойств и конверторов:

```
<Grid> 
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Auto}"/>
    <Label Content="Список пуст">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Auto.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>        
</Grid>
```

`ListBox` и `Label` должны находится в одном `Grid`(или хотя бы в одной ячейке) чтобы происходило наложение друг на друга.

Answer (score 3):

Сначала напишем конвертер, который является отражением BooleanToVisibilityConverter:

```
public class InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

После этого дополним модель представления признаком наличия автомобилей:

```
class ViewModel
{
    ...

    public bool HasAuto
    {
        get { return Auto.Any(); }
    }
}
```

После этого добавим обработку видимости в представление:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <local:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ListBox Visibility="{Binding HasAuto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Auto}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuto}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Список пуст. Введите данные" Visibility="{Binding HasAuto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Остается только вовремя обновлять свойство `HasAuto` путем вызова `PropertyChanged`. Это можно сделать подписавшись на событие изменения коллекции `Auto`. Или можно вызывать событие `PropertyChanged` при загрузке, добавлении и удалении элементов из коллекции. Тогда подписка на событие изменения состава коллекции не понадобится.

**UPD**

Ну или можно воспользоваться триггерами (свойство `HasAuto` все равно понадобится)

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AutoListTemplate">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Auto}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuto}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EmptyAutoListTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Список пуст. Введите данные" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasAuto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EmptyAutoListTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AutoListTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но есть пару вопросов:
1) что за метод `Any()`
2) что за `<StackPanel.Resources>` и где ее описывать?

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr, 1) это метод расширения для IEnumerable [клик](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx). 2) Это контейнер, в котором находился `ListBox` и `TextBlock`. У вас он может быть любым. 3) посмотрите второй вариант. Возможно, он вам больше понравится. Во втором варианте как раз меняется `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Объявите:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Auto
```

2. В разметке:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Auto.Count}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Auto.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

3. Аналогично `Auto` (только поменять `Hidden/Visible`)